# 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute' using async/await

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, async-await, enumeration

I have a simple Unit Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestInitDatabases()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Testing loading up all databases!");

    Assert.IsTrue(Library.InitDatabase());
}
```

And a Method in a ClassLibrary that is attempting to load an Entity with 58,139 records.

```
public static bool InitDatabase()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Loading Entities");

    var startTime = DateTime.Now;

    DContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
    DContext.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

    Task task = new Task(async () => await DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.LoadAsync());

    Debug.WriteLine("All Tasks Assigned");

    task.Start();
    task.Wait();
    while (!DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.Local.Any())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Task Status " + task.Status);
    }

    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("We are about to count the records...");

        while (DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.Local.Count != 58139)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OrderHistory has " + DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.Local.Count + " Records");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Count Error: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Total Load Time: " + (DateTime.Now – startTime));

    return true;
}
```

But the try/catch returns:

> Count Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Every time I run the test.

Output shows:

```
...
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 1 Records
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Count Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.TestFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter.dll
The thread 'Agent: adapter run thread for test 'TestInitDatabases' with id '97fef094-3e43-4bfa-bb1d-02b70eb4b6f7'' (0x19ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Agent: test queue thread' (0x3a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Agent: state execution thread for test 'TestInitDatabases' with id '97fef094-3e43-4bfa-bb1d-02b70eb4b6f7'' (0x138c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
...
```

Occasionally, I'll get:

```
...
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 1 Records
OrderHistory has 513 Records
```

then the same error. I am trying to find the fastest way to Load the Entity Table.

**EDIT:** I changed my Method according to Yuval Itzchakov's comment:

```
    public static async void InitDatabase()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Loading Entities");

        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime newTime;


        DContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
        DContext.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

        try
        {
            await DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.LoadAsync();
            //DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.Load();
            Debug.WriteLine("Orders has " + DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.Local.Count + " records");
            Debug.WriteLine("OrderHistory Loaded: " + (DateTime.Now - startTime));
            newTime = DateTime.Now;
            await DContext.SA_HistoryDetail.LoadAsync();
            //DContext.SA_HistoryDetail.Load();
            Debug.WriteLine("Details has " + DContext.SA_HistoryDetail.Local.Count + " records");
            Debug.WriteLine("OrderDetails Loaded: " + (DateTime.Now - newTime));
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            foreach (SqlError error in ex.Errors)
            Debug.WriteLine("Sql Exception Error: " + error.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread - caught ThreadAbortException - resetting.");
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception message: {0}", ex.Message));
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Load Exception Error: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("All Tasks Complete: " + (DateTime.Now - startTime));

        return;
    }
```

When I use plain old Load the Orders Entity is loaded in ~47 seconds. The Details Entity takes ~19 minutes to load (358,501 records).

When I change (Comment/Uncomment) to the LoadAsync all I get are thread abort exceptions.

Comment: Do you want to actually wait until `LoadAsync` finishes? cause that's not what's currently happening.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Yes I would like to wait for LoadAsync to finish.

Comment: just `await LoadAsync`. No need for all your tasks stuff, you're overcomplicating things  and introduce bugs.

Comment: Using a static DbContext is almost always the wrong thing to do, DbContext is not thread safe and should not have more than one thread touching it at the same time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Color me ignorant. What are my alternatives to static DbContext in a class library?

Comment: You make a separate DbContext as needed in `using` statements. `DbContext` was designed with the idea that it would have many short lived instances, one singular long lived instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is currently happening is that your actually awaiting the outter task created by `new Task`, which means that when you use `Task.Wait`, it will return immediately and not wait for the inner task to finish.

I don't see a reason to create a `new Task` when the operation you're doing is IO bound, you can simply  `await` the operation:

```
await DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.LoadAsync()
```

This will guarantee the operation finishes collecting the data before you look at the `Count` property.